# Date.getTime() is returning the previous day

Tags: android, date, kotlin, datepicker, simpledateformat

I'm parsing a date in with `dd-MM-yyyy` format and returning in seconds (dividing it by 1000). The problem comes when I convert it to Unix Time Stamp, because it converts this seconds to the previous day. I will explain with my code and an example:

```
private fun String.toTimestamp(): String {
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
    return (dateFormat.parse(this).time / 1000).toString
}
```

If the date is `01/02/2019` (2nd February 2019), this method returns `1548975600`. If you convert it to a date (I'm using [this](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) page) it returns `01/31/2019 @ 11:00pm (UTC)`. I've tried adding hour, minutes and seconds, even adding the time zone, but it always returns the day before.

Another example:
`13-02-2019` > `1550012400` > `02/12/2019 @ 11:00pm (UTC)`

The date comes from a `DatePicker`, but if I create it in the next way it returns the correct day:

```
(Date().time / 1000).toString()
```

I've tried with the system's language in Spanish and in English, and changing the `Locale` to `Locale.ENGLISH` and `Locale("es", "ES")` and the results are the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What time zone your device is on?

Comment: Spanish, but I've tried also with `Locale.ENGLISH`, `Locale("es", "ES")` and with another device with the system language in English and the results are the same.

Comment: It is not todo with locale but to do with your device time zone. Spain is current in GMT+1 which is 1 hour ahead of UTC. Thus 13-02-2019 00:00:00 in Spain is 12-02-2019 23:00:00 in UTC.

Comment: By dd-MM-yyyy you loose the +0300 etc for example.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: What is the expected timestamp value? The time at midnight (00:00) UTC??

Comment: What does your date picker return? A `Date`? A `String`? Three `int`s for year, month and day? Or…? Asking so that we can avoid doing more conversions than necessary.

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm trying to get the correct milliseconds of the `Date` I'm introducing as parameter. But when I convert this milliseconds applying the Unix format, I obtain a `Date` corresponding to the previous day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

In Java syntax:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");

public static final String toTimestamp(String dateString) {
    long epochSecond = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toEpochSecond();
    return String.valueOf(epochSecond);
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    System.out.println(toTimestamp("13-02-2019"));
```

> 1550016000

Check this value on the *Epoch Unix Time Stamp Converter* that you linked to:

> 02/13/2019 @ 12:00am (UTC)

`SimpleDateFormat` is notoriously troublesome and along with `Date` long outdated. Instead I use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. This forces us to give time zone or offset explicitly. In this case as the predefined constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`. Which in turn makes sure we get the correct result and thus solves your problem. A further minor advantages is it gives us *seconds* since the epoch so we don’t need the funny-looking division by 1000.

Imports I used were:

```
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;
import org.threeten.bp.ZoneOffset;
import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in. In this case import from the `java.time` package (not `org.threeten.bp`).
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: I'm using this way (`AndroidThreeTen` library) adding `hh:mm:ss` and it works perfectly but when hours are from 13 to 23 I receive this exception: `DateTimeParseException: Text '31-12-2019 23:59:59' could not be parsed: Invalid value for ClockHourOfAmPm (valid values 1 - 12): 23`. How can I set PM or 24 hours format?

Comment: You probably just need uppercase `HH` for hour of day from 00 through 23 (lowercase `hh` is for hour within AM or PM, from 01 through 12).

Comment: Of course, what a mistake! Now it works perfect, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
//convert seconds to date try below function
public static String convertSecondsToDate(Long date) {
    try {
        long dateInMiliseconds = date *1000;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(dateInMiliseconds);
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```